# Angular - my ngIf hides an input-label only once

Tags: javascript, html, angular

`*ngIf="currentIdea.oetSupportNeeded"` I have a dropdown list with 2 values - yes and no, and another input label where you can write freely. I want to show the `input-label` only when user chose "yes" in the dropdown list and to hide it when "no" is chosen.

My problem is that the following code works only once - when page loads and "no" is chosen, the input label is hidden, but when you choose "yes" and then "no" again, the label shows up and doesn't disappear anymore. I want it to toggle on/off depending on the user's choice

I tried using `ngShow`, `ngHide`, `[disabled]`, etc. Nothing helped

```html
<div class="select-wrapper" [ngClass]="{'select-wrapper-blocked': isNotAdmin()}">
            <select class="input-control" [(ngModel)]="booleanVariable">
                <option value="false">No</option>
                <option value="true">Yes</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col form-input" [ngClass]="{'form-input-blocked': isNotAdmin()}">
        <p class="input-label">
            Some text
        </p>
        <input *ngIf="booleanVariable" class="input-control" [(ngModel)]="stringVariable" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Right, I pasted wrong version, updated the code

Comment: You use `false` and `true` as strings. Try this: `[value]="true"`, `[value]="false"`. First time this work because of `currentIdea.oetSupportNeeded` is undefined I think

Answer (score 1):

You are using true and false as strings. You can change the test into your ngIf.

Like

```js
<select [(ngModel)]="foo">
  <option [ngValue]="true">true</option>
  <option [ngValue]="false">false</option>
</select>
<input *ngIf="foo == true"/>
```

And to define a default value, you can set the value of `foo` into the class like

```
public foo = true;
```

Comment: Your solution worked, but cause another error - now when I open a page that has "yes" by default the label is hidden and i have to choose "no" and then "yes" again. I suppose it is the case, because value gets set to "false" by default or something...

Comment: If foo is boolean, then is should be declare as boolean.

Comment: @SaimaHaji No because it's not a boolean with the last edit version. I use now `ngValue` like that `foo` is a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ngModelChange** event and make a function to typecast the data.

Check the link for example. [Show Hide Field using *ngIf](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y5k1yh)

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you shared, the value of your select menu is bound to the `booleanVariable` property of your component. 
Your `*ngIf` queries another property, so the condition is wrong. You should be checking the `booleanVariable` in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me few hours ago. The problem was that

`<option value="false">No</option>
<option value="true">Yes</option>`

was wrong. I solved it with

`<option [value]="false">No</option>
<option [value]="true">Yes</option>`

That's because otherwise Angular does not "analyze" the value of the option but recognizes it as a string.